# Bash Create New Dirs and Write Content of each line to File in New Dir

Tags: bash

I have a file called `events`.  What I want to do is read this file, and for each line in the file, create new directories, called `dir1` ... `dirn` where `n` is the line number in the `events` file.  Then I want to write each line into a text file called `inp.dat`.  For example, if `events` file looks like this:

```
{'lat': 13.96, 'lon': -91.87, 'dep': 14, 'time': UTCDateTime('2019-11-30-07:44:23')}
{'lat': 38.94, 'lon': 143.44, 'dep': 49, 'time': UTCDateTime('2019-11-29-04:01:39')}
{'lat': -60.85, 'lon': -50.96, 'dep': 16, 'time': UTCDateTime('2019-11-28-00:26:31')}
{'lat': 19.22, 'lon': 94.94, 'dep': 75, 'time': UTCDateTime('2019-11-26-11:05:58')}
```

I want to create 4 directories, `dir1`,`dir2`,`dir3`,`dir4` , and within each directory have a file `inp.dat` contain the contents of the respective line.  For example in `dir1`, I want `inp.dat` to have just `{'lat': 13.96, 'lon': -91.87, 'dep': 14, 'time': UTCDateTime('2019-11-30-07:44:23')}`.

How would I go about writing this script? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This sounds pretty easy

Comment: Hi Oguz, I'm fairly new to bash scripting, so any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more quotes than needed for this concrete example:

```
#!/bin/bash
let num=0
while read line
do
    let num++
    mkdir -p "dir${num}"
    printf '%s\n' "$line" > "dir${num}/inp.dat"
done < events
```